# Забить память по максимуму

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x, запрос

Вопрос: Возможно ли как-то указать в sql запросе модерируемый объем памяти?
Предположим есть большая база данных, а у меня всего 4 гб свободной пямяти (может быть и больше и меньше). Я хочу выбрать **максимальное** кол-во строк и присвоить этот список переменной, так чтобы компьютер не зависнул.

Что-то вроде этого:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
db_connection = 'mysql+pymysql://Baron:Baroness@localhost/test_base'
conn = create_engine(db_connection)
data = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE (указание на свободную память)", conn)
```

Или может есть какая-то модерируемая настройка памяти в самой Mysql для определенных таблиц?

Comment: Если вы объясните для чего это вам, то возможно вам посоветуют подходящее решение...

Comment: К сожалению я имею достаточно старое компьютерное железо. Поэтому я не могу загружать всю БД, а также она бесконечно дополняется. Поэтому мне нужно получать случайную выборку из базы данных, для дальнейшего использования ее в машинном обучении, так чтобы эта выборка была максимального размера при любых условиях. Например, если я отключаю большинство процессов, то буду иметь до 80% свободной памяти. Нужно запросить столько строк, сколько поместится в высвобожденной памяти т.е в этих 80-ти процентах. А также чтобы не было в ущерб самой программе(не зависло во время обработки).

Comment: Все известные мне алгоритмы машинного обучения будут создавать дополнительные временные и результируюшие матрицы в памяти, поэтому при первом вызове `model.fit(X_train, y_train)` - вы получите `MemoryError` при таком подходе... )

Comment: В любом случае добавить физически оперативную память стоит дешевле, чем писать обработчик для оптимизации)

Comment: согласен с @AndreyIvasko. Вместо апгрейда собственного железа можно использовать вычисления в облаке и платить только за время реального использования виртуальной машины... А после обучения модели сервер можно "потушить"...

Comment: К моему сожалению, я небогатый студент и у меня едва ли хватает средств на нормальное питание. Так что этот вариант мне не подойдет.

Comment: Для "небогатого студента" есть неплохой вариант решения проблемы облачных вычислений. Google Cloud при регистрации дает немного денег на счет для использования их на обучение их платформе. Их можно потратить на любой сервис, в т.ч. на их VPS. Кажется, дают $300 с условием потратить максимум за год (что не потратил - аннулируется). Я свои не потратил... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все известные мне алгоритмы машинного обучения будут создавать дополнительные временные и результируюшие матрицы в памяти, поэтому при первом же вызове `model.fit(X_train, y_train)` - вы скорее всего получите `MemoryError` при таком подходе...

В реляционных БД обычно можно указать максимальное число строк, которое вы хотите получить:

```
N = 10**5
sql = f"SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY rand() LIMIT {N}"
data = pd.read_sql(sql, conn)
```

Число строк `N` можно попытаться посчитать динамически - например прочитать 1000 строк из БД в DataFrame и посмотреть сколько памяти занимает данный DF (`df.memory_usage().sum()`) и дальше расчитать сколько строк нужно читать...

Comment: А вы случаем не знаете, как можно просчитать количество выделяемой памяти для временных и результирующих таблиц? Может есть какой-то алгоритм? Я понимаю что это зависит от моей архитектуры. Но все же . . .

Comment: вам придется делать `memory profiling` для каждой функции и высчитывать на сколько процентов увеличилось использование памяти после вызова функции - это очень муторная задача...

Comment: Хотел бы задать последний вопрос немножечко не по теме. Я собираюсь использовать машинное обучение с подкреплением. Влияет ли вообще количество выборки на принятие решения. Я провожу аналогию так, как если бы я имел больше опыта, то мог бы принимать более обдуманные решения. То есть если компьютер обработает большее количество данных, он сможет подойти к вопросу более объективно. Верно ли мое суждение? Мой вопрос имеет корни в этом суждении. Может я не верно понимаю? И вообще количество выборки не оказывает такого большого влияние на принятие решения?

Comment: я думаю размер и качество обучающей выборки будет играть одну из решающих ролей...

Comment: Значит мое запутанное представление оказалось верно... Теперь бы понять как делать memory profiling. Что ж, я пожалуй пойду. Спасибо, за прояснение этого крупного для меня вопроса.